# Extract ordinal Year

Tags: r, time

I have a data frame as follows:

```
 Name      Year
  a        2010
  b        2010
  c        2011
  d        2011
  e        2012
```

I want to create a column with the ordinal Year like

```
 1
 1
 2
 2
 3
```

Comment: Try `as.numeric(as.factor(df$year))`

Comment: @jay.sf that does not work for ```c(2010,2010,2011,2012,2015)```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "ordinal year".

Comment: @M-M True, method refined in answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another question. 
If I have list of date: 01-01-2019, 01-02-2019 How can I get only the first day of the year in the list?

Comment: @Spacedman actually it's just like 1st, 2nd...

Comment: What if there's a missing year? If there's no 2011 in your data would 2012 be 2? Does it matter what order it appears in? Is it really just the number of years since the first year plus 1?

Comment: Doesn't matter if there is a gap year. just number of years since the 1st year

Comment: @JennyPham if you have another question then start a new post, after first doing some research to see if it has already been answered or if the answer is available via the R documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
> d$ordinalyear = d$Year - min(d$Year) + 1
> d
  Name Year ordinalyear
1    a 2010           1
2    b 2010           1
3    c 2011           2
4    d 2011           2
5    e 2012           3
```

Assuming by "ordinal year" you mean "year since the first year in my data starting at 1".

Answer (score 1):

We may transform to factor and back to numeric, by defining levels over the range of years.

```
transform(DF, year.o=as.numeric(factor(year, levels=min(year):max(year))))
#             x year year.o
# 1  -0.1270936 2010      1
# 2   1.4348448 2010      1
# 3   0.5876282 2011      2
# 4  -0.5088915 2012      3
# 5   1.3284993 2014      5
# 6   3.1037108 2015      6
# 7  -1.5972415 2016      7
# 8  -0.3736655 2016      7
# 9   1.0019033 2019     10
```

#### Data

```
DF <- structure(list(x = c(-0.127093595434297, 1.43484479335631, 0.58762817447056, 
-0.508891454974585, 1.32849927769338, 3.10371076154511, -1.59724145798092, 
-0.373665500318562, 1.00190327654304, -0.457699175902573), year = c(2010L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2019L, 2019L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Equivalent to subtracting `min(year)+1`, in a roundabout way.

Comment: @Spacedman Many ways lead to Rome

Comment: Perhaps, but I would say this is via a twisty path rather than the straight roads the Romans preferred. Its doing a load of char-num-char conversions, a matching operation, and computing a sequence. The mathematical approach seems more direct to me.